# DRF Serialize only selected keys of JSONField

Tags: django, django-models, django-rest-framework

I want to serialize specified key:value pair of `JSONField` in DRF but not the whole `JSON`.

What I got from their website:

Starting from Django Rest Framework 3.12, the `JSONField` of Django is supported. **Nested search** with JSONField started to be supported with double underscore notation as used in Django itself.

You can read the exact statement from https://www.django-rest-framework.org/community/3.12-announcement/#support-for-jsonfield

---

But I didn't find anything related to my problem.

When I use double underscore notation for serialization (ex. `details__link`), I get error saying model doesn't contain that field.